# Perl, open2, stdin does not operate

Tags: perl, gnuplot, stdin

I'm trying to run "gnuplot" process and send commands to it with open2, but nothing happens. I'm new in perl, so i'm little bit confused with how things work, official documentation about this module isn't clear to me.

```
use IPC::Open2;
use strict;
use warnings;

my($w, $r);

my $pid = open2($w, $r, "gnuplot") or die "$!";
# print "pid was $pid\n";
print $w "reset\n";
print $w "dx=5.\n";
print $w "n=2\n";
print $w "total_box_width_relative=0.75\n";
print $w "gap_width_relative=0.1\n";
print $w "d_width=(gap_width_relative+total_box_width_relative)*dx/2.\n";
print $w "reset\n";
print $w "set term png truecolor font 'arial,10' fontscale 1.0 size 800, 400\n";
print $w "set output 'test.png'\n";
print $w "set xlabel 'time' offset '0', '-2'\n";
print $w "set ylabel 'load'\n";
print $w "set autoscale xfixmin\n";
print $w "set autoscale xfixmax\n";
print $w "set autoscale y\n";
print $w "set datafile separator '\\t'\n";
print $w "set xdata time\n";
print $w "set timefmt '%d-%m-%Y'\n";
print $w "set xrange ['08-12-2016':'23-02-2025']\n";
print $w "set format x '%m/%d/%Y'\n";
print $w "set xtic rotate by 30 offset character -4,-2\n";
print $w "set xtics font ', 8'\n";
print $w "set grid\n";
print $w "set boxwidth total_box_width_relative/n relative\n";
print $w "set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder\n";
print $w "plot 'test.dat' u 1:2 w boxes lc rgb'blue' notitle,\\\n";
print $w "   'test.dat' u 1:3 w boxes lc rgb'red' notitle\n";
close($w);
waitpid($pid, 0);
if ($?) {
    print "That child exited with wait status of $?\n";
}
```

test.dat structure example:

```
08-12-2016  3   6
09-12-2016  56  44
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you've got the ordering of file handles the wrong way around in `open2`:

```
 $pid = open2($chld_out, $chld_in, 'some', 'cmd', 'and', 'args');
```

E.g. the `$w` in your example is `STDOUT` for the process, and so you printing to it isn't going to do anything at all. And because you're doing `waitpid` - and closing the 'output' filehandle - you'll be waiting indefinitely, because the process is still reading from it's input file handle.

I would also really strongly suggest that single letter variable names are a bad idea anyway. You can embed the `my` in the `open2` statement too, so:

```
my $pid = open2 ( my $child_out, my $child_in, "gnuplot" );
```

And as a couple of minor style points - I'd suggest that replicating `print $w` over and over isn't really the ideal way of doing it.

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open2;
use IO::Select;

my $pid = open2( my $gnuplot_out, my $gnuplot_in, "gnuplot" );
my $select = IO::Select->new($gnuplot_out);

while ( my $command = <DATA> ) {
   print {$gnuplot_in} $command;
   while ( $select->can_read(0) ) {
      print "Response from gnuplot: ", scalar <$gnuplot_out>, "\n";
   }
}

close($gnuplot_in);
while ( $select->can_read(0) ) {
   print "Response from gnuplot: ", scalar <$gnuplot_out>, "\n";
}

close($gnuplot_out);
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
if ($?) {
   print "That child exited with wait status of $?\n";
}

__DATA__
reset
dx=5.
n=2
total_box_width_relative=0.75
gap_width_relative=0.1
d_width=(gap_width_relative+total_box_width_relative)*dx/2.
reset
set term png truecolor font 'arial,10' fontscale 1.0 size 800, 400
set output 'test.png'
set xlabel 'time' offset '0', '-2'
set ylabel 'load'
set autoscale xfixmin
set autoscale xfixmax
set autoscale y
set datafile separator '\\t'
set xdata time
set timefmt '%d-%m-%Y'
set xrange ['08-12-2016':'23-02-2025']
set format x '%m/%d/%Y'
set xtic rotate by 30 offset character -4,-2
set xtics font ', 8'
set grid
set boxwidth total_box_width_relative/n relative
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
plot 'test.dat' u 1:2 w boxes lc rgb'blue' notitle,\\
   'test.dat' u 1:3 w boxes lc rgb'red' notitle
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's a little bit closer, gnuplot errors are responding, but still, the script starts and doing nothing. The only thing i can do is manual ctrl+c interrupt, but even then, some gnuplot daemons are still in memory, and cmd is closing with its dialog window "do you really want to close process".

Comment: Seems like gnuplot doesn't like "plot" line, in any way i tried (single slash, dowble slash, oneliner etc), but only in .pl file. If we run same code in gnuplot - everything is ok.

Comment: OK, So that could be as simple as the `\\` - which I presume is a line separator? Could that be wrapped onto a single line? (Not really all that familiar with gnuplot)

Comment: No, even if we remove slash and write two lines as one, as it supposed to be - gnuplot will show you error message about "all points y value undefined"